# How to use google cloud logging at a lumen/laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, logging, google-cloud-platform, lumen

I would like to know how to use **google cloud logging** library at a **lumen\laravel** application, there are [some examples for php](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/php?hl=en), but I would like to know how to implement in the best way at that framework.

Comment: If you're using Monolog 3 you have to use `"google/cloud-logging": "^1.25"` due to PSR-3 changes

  `Declaration of Google\Cloud\Logging\PsrLogger::emergency($message, array $context = []) must be compatible with Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::emergency(Stringable|string $message, array $context = []): void`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lumen seems to work the same logging infrastructure as Laravel does. By default it uses Monolog which is a PSR-3 compatible logging library but I think the following code might also work for logging with Google cloud:

Create the logger factory class:

```
class CreateGoogleCloudLogger {
    public function __invoke() {
       $logging = new LoggingClient([
          'projectId' => $projectId
       ]);
       return $logging->psrLogger('app');      
    }
}
```

Change your `.env` file:

```
LOG_CHANNEL=googlecloud
```

Then add this in your `AppServiceProvider` register function

```
config(['logging.channels.googlecloud' => [
    'driver' => 'custom',
    'via' => App\Logging\CreateGoogleCloudLogger::class,
] ]);
```

This should use the factory to create a PSR-3 compatible logger.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I need to call directly that channel, I can use `Log::channel('googlecloud')->info('Something happened!');` It's that right?

Comment: Yes, the shared code also makes it the default log channel (if you change the .env) setting but if you don't want to do that then `Log::channel` will allow you to selectively log to that

Comment: The answer was really helpful, thanks for the information.

Comment: Possibly one more improvement to this can be that don't register the function in the service provider. Use, `logging.php` to define the new channel and that also gives you a place to define your `projectId` config variable.

Answer (score 2):

I found the accepted answer did not work for me when used in a `stack` channel (which is Laravel 9's default configuration). This seems to be due to the stack channel requiring Monolog loggers, not just PSR-3 loggers
To make that work I copied (or "took inspiration from") https://github.com/einnar82/google-stack-driver

Made no changes to `app.php`.

In `.env` (note you'll need to set your actual values here)

```
LOG_LEVEL=debug
LOG_CHANNELS=single,googlecloud
GOOGLE_PROJECT=my-project-name-from-google
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/var/www/somepath/credentials-file-from-google.json
```

In `logging.php`:

```
'googleProjectId' => env('GOOGLE_PROJECT'),
'channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => explode(',', env('LOG_CHANNELS', 'single')),
        'ignore_exceptions' => false,
    ],

    'single' => [
        'driver' => 'single',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
    ],

    'googlecloud' => [
        'driver' => 'custom',
        'via' => \App\Logging\CreateGoogleCloudLogger::class,
        'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
    ],
];
```

in `app/Logging/CreateGoogleCloudLogger.php`

```
namespace App\Logging;

use Google\Cloud\Logging\LoggingClient;
use Monolog\Handler\PsrHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;


class CreateGoogleCloudLogger
{
    public function __invoke(array $config)
    {
        $logName = config('app.name');
        $logging = new LoggingClient([
            'projectId' => config('logging.googleProjectId')
        ]);
        $psrLogger = $logging->psrLogger($logName);

        $handler = new PsrHandler($psrLogger);
        return new Logger($logName, [$handler]);
    }
}
```

Then in your application at any point you can just do...

```
Log::debug('This is a log message');
try {
    $var = $this->doSomethingRisky();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    Log::warning('The risky thing failed but we will carry on anyway', ['message' => $e->getMessage()]);
    $var = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Laravel uses the Monolog Logger, you can make use of it. Just recently, Monolog did add support for the Google Cloud.

The explanation below does work for Laravel AND Lumen.

### It's one config change only

You only need to change one config setting.

Set the GoogleCloudLoggingFormatter in your .env file like this:

```bash
LOG_STDERR_FORMATTER=\Monolog\Formatter\GoogleCloudLoggingFormatter::class
```

OR define it inside your `config/logging.php`

```php
'stderr' => [
    'driver' => 'monolog',
    'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
    'handler' => StreamHandler::class,
    'formatter' => env('LOG_STDERR_FORMATTER', \Monolog\Formatter\GoogleCloudLoggingFormatter::class),
    'with' => [
        'stream' => 'php://stderr',
    ],
],
```

Remember to choose the stderr logging channel. You could also rename it if you prefer a different channel name.

### Google Cloud Logging Package

The Google Cloud Logging Package does work, but it's one more dependency you don't need. Nothing wrong with it, but why not keep it simple?

### Monolog supports Google from Version >= 2.8.0 or >= 3.2.0.

If you're using an old version, you can write a custom Formatter instead, achieving the same.

#### Do you need more information?

Just a few days ago, I did write an article about it. Feel welcome to read it in case you want more information:
https://jonassiewertsen.com/blog/laravel-logging-show-correct-severity-levels-on-the-google-cloud-platform

Answer (score 0):

I am using Laravel 10 and the above solution almost worked out of the box. I had to wrap in a class that implements Monolog\Handler\HandlerInterface.

```
// config/logging.php
    'googlecloud' => [
        'driver' => 'custom',
        'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
        'via' => \App\Helpers\GoogleCloudLogger::class,
    ],

// app/helpers/GoogleCloudLogger.php
    <?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use Google\Cloud\Logging\LoggingClient;
use Google\Cloud\Logging\PsrLogger;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\LogRecord;
use Monolog\Handler\HandlerInterface;

class GoogleCloudLogger
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        $logging = new LoggingClient([
           'projectId' => env('GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID', '')
        ]);

    $logger = $logging->psrLogger(config('app.name'), [
        'batchEnabled' => true,
    ]);

    return new Logger(
        config('app.name'),
        [
            new class ($logger) implements HandlerInterface {
                public function __construct(
                    public PsrLogger $logger
                ) {
                }

                public function isHandling(LogRecord $record): bool
                {
                    return true;
                }

                public function handle(LogRecord $record): bool
                {
                    $this->logger->log(
                        $record->level->name,
                        $record->message,
                        $record->context
                    );

                    return true;
                }

                public function handleBatch(array $records): void
                {
                    foreach ($records as $record) {
                        $this->handle($record);
                    }
                }

                public function close(): void
                {
                }
            },
        ]
    );
}
```

}